# Deploy a rails app, on step 2.2, bundle install states "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle-install

I am new to the whole ruby rails scene, and I am installing for the first time. I have followed the instructions to a T, including putting everything in the suggested directories. I've been researching this issue for hours and the closest I came to a fix is reinstalling and that did not work.

My issue is, while following the install instructions from railsbridge.org and upon reaching step 2.2, when I try to run bundle install, it keeps stating "The system cannot find the path specified." This worked fine up until this point in the tutorial.

Comment: Hi, wecome to stackoverflow and Rails. Could you include your full error with your question? Most errors aren't really general enough that one can understand them without looking at the trace and referencing the application's code.

Comment: I am in my working folder inside the command prompt with ruby rails, and I type in either "bundle install" or "bundle install --without production" and it gives me the error "The system cannot find the path specified." and because of that I am unable to continue with the instructions given on the website. Or are you asking for the code in the file?

Comment: is that the entire error? Do you have a Gemfile in the directory where you're running the `bundle` command from?

Comment: Yes that is the entire error, nothing else appeared before or after it and no issues up until this point.There is in fact a gem file and a gemlock file both in the directory I'm running bundle in. I have not edited anything or deviated even the slightest from the tutorials. I even started over from scratch and in the same exact spot I am stuck with that error message. I don't know if it helps or matters, but I am running windows 10.

Comment: I see. I have practically no experience coding on windows (linuxxer myself), so probably can't help you there.

Comment: I love Linux/OS X. I had been using Ubuntu, but was having keyboard and performance issues on this laptop, so I went back to windows. Determined to make the most out of this crappy Toshiba, and after hours of no fix for windows... I resorted to install after install of Linux, until I found a distro running without much issue! I thank you for your effort though! At least at this point and time there is no fix. It is probably hardware related. This laptop does some strange things I never heard of (Satelite C875D-S7225). Also, I used a friends desktop computer running windows 10 without issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Missing Bundler installation.
use

```
gem install bundler
```

and try again :)